# Создание кнопки для скачивания документа

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите скрипт, чтобы при клике на кнопку предлагалось скачивание файла (при подтверждении скачивался файл) ? 
вот пример кнопки:

```
<button type='submit' class='wow fadeInRight' data-wow-delay='2s'>/
```

И вот, например, название файла:
kolbasa-primer.xlsx

Comment: Обязательно использовать button?

Comment: ну желательно, просто уже стили заточены под нее, но если все можно сделать гораздо проще ссылкой, тогда можно и ссылкой

Comment: <a href="kolbasa-primer.xlsx" download>Скачать</a>

Comment: Этот вариант я находил, но поддерживается эта функция в малом количестве браузеров, нужно чтобы работало и на старый сайтах, поэтому и ищу скрипт.

Answer (score 1):

Самый просто способ - использовать прямую ссылку на файл:

```
<a href="http://example.com/kolbasa-primer.xlsx" target="_blank">Скачать</a>
```

Кроме того, используя HTML5, можно указать аттрибут [download](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp):

```
<a href="http://example.com/kolbasa-primer.xlsx" download>Скачать</a>
```

И, наконец, пример скрипта для скачивания файла:

HTML:

```
<a href="download.php">Скачать</a>
```

download.php

```
$file = '<путь к файлу>';

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

readfile($file);
```

Comment: Подскажите, нужно создать файл download.php  и прописать в него нижние скрипты ?

Comment: Да, вы можете создать любой php-файл (например, наш download.php). и скопировать приведенный выше код. Не забудьте указать в нем правильный путь к скачиваемому файлу.

Comment: $file = 'elvideo-price.xlsx'; header("Cache-Control: public"); header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file"); header("Content-Type: application/zip"); header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); readfile($file);

Пишет вот такую вот ошибку

Comment: подскажите, что не так делаю ?

Comment: @SvArt713 Для начала, все-таки, напишите текст сообщения об ошибке

Answer (score 0):

Использовать [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) в случаи, если к примеру, был отменён **confirm()**.

```js
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.file');
    // Вешаем обработчик "click" на все элементы с классом file
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            // Отменяем событие (преход по ссылке или submit) если "Отмена"
            if (!confirm('Точно будем качать?')) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }, false);
    }
```

```html
<a class="file" href="file.pdf">Скачать файл 1</a>
<a class="file" href="file.doc">Скачать файл 2</a>
<hr>
<form action="/" method="post">
    <button class='wow fadeInRight file' data-wow-delay='2s' type='submit'>Скачать</button>
</form>
```

*confirm()* само собой можно заменить на то, что требуется (модальное окно например)

Comment: Скажите, этот скрипт нужно пробовать уже на сервере или можно и на ПК, потому как я изменил, но не скачка не работает

Comment: Ссылки работают и сейчас в примере, и "на ПК" тоже прекрасно будут работать. Логика проста: При клике на ссылку выскакивает `confirm` если нажали "отмена", то отменяем переход по ссылке на `file.pdf`, а если нажали "ok", то ссылка ведёт себя как обычно, без изменений. С кнопкой и submit я не могу знать, что там у Вас происходит по нажатию на кнопку, куда и что отправляется. В примере выше при клике на кнопку и "отмене" происходит отмена `submit`.

Comment: так переход на файл происходит, но мне нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку просто скачивало файл.